# How to set curly braces'/parentheses'/square brackets'/arithmetic operators' syntax highlight color in VIM?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, parentheses, curly-braces

How do I highlight operators/parentheses/brackets/etc. in VIM? I'm not interested in coloring matching or unmatching parentheses/brackets.

I've tried ":hi cBracket/whatnot guifg=something" and ":hi Operator/cOperator guifg=something" but these don't seem to affect anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two parts to Vim syntax coloring: the `syn` command and the `hi` command.

As far as I understand, you use `syn` to define syntax.  For example:

```
syn match parens /[(){}]/
```

Then you use `hi` to tell Vim how to highlight `parens`:

```
hi parens ctermfg=red
```

Answer (score 3):

See 
    :h pi_paren.txt
about highlighting matching parens:

```
To disable the plugin after it was loaded use this command: >
    :NoMatchParen
And to enable it again: >
    :DoMatchParen
The highlighting used is MatchParen.  You can specify different colors with
the ":highlight" command.  Example: >
    :hi MatchParen ctermbg=blue guibg=lightblue

 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution above breaks code folding that's syntax based (because of the rules with {} overriding something previous). I haven't been able to figure out how to get around this...

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in your .vimrc for red colored (), {}

```
autocmd BufRead, BufNewFile * syn match parens /[(){}]/ | hi parens ctermfg=red
```

You can do the same for squared brackets, but you need to escape the bracket characters, put the following in your .vimrc for colored []

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile * syn match brack /[\[\]]/ | hi brack ctermfg=red
```